# QNAP MySQL container: "You need to specify one of the following as an environment variable"

Tags: containers, qnap

In my QNAP NAS, I've installed a MySQL container, but after trying to start it, there is a console error:

```
You need to specify one of the following as an environment variable: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, MYSQL_ALLLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD, _MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD.
```

I can't see any way to configure the container with such variables. I can see the configuration in `Inspect`, but this is not editable. Separate to `Inspect`, if I click `Edit`, I cannot add any such variable.

If I click `Attach Terminal`, there is an error `"Container not running"`, and I can't start the container due to the error above.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Can you add what have you done during `I've installed a MySQL container`, when creating there should be `Environment` section in `Advanced Settings`, there you can specify for example `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` and value `root`

Comment: Thanks @zori. That fixed that. If I deploy a `phpMyAdmin` Docker container using the same process, is there any configuration I need to make to have it connect to the MySQL server? When trying to login with `root/root` to phpMyAdmin, I receive an error `Cannot log in to the MySQL server`.

Comment: You need to provide more details and probably new question what have you done, normally you as server name you should provide mysql container name, also you need to have connection between them if I'm correct it's called `virtual switch` in QNAP. More info you can find on [Docker Hub phpMyAdmin](https://hub.docker.com/_/phpmyadmin) it's good to provide env variable `PMA_ARBITRARY=1` it will allows you to provide server name, so it can be via ip or hostname. Unfortunately I don't QNAP to give more details

Comment: [New question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77893537/qnap-phpmyadmin-container-phpmyadmin-tried-to-connect-to-the-mysql-server-and) @zori.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we got in comment, when creating MySQL container there should be `Environment section` in `Advanced Settings`, there you can specify for example `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` and value `root`

Before creating any container I encourage your to read documentation on https://hub.docker.com, in this case it will be https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql. There you can find many information that will help you to prepare it correctly