# QNAP phpMyAdmin container: "phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection"

Tags: mysql, docker, phpmyadmin, containers, qnap

In a QNAP NAS, there is a MySQL Docker container with:

- IP address: 10.0.3.3
- MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
- Port forwarding: 32774 → 33060/TCP

When creating the phpMyAdmin Docker container, I specified:

- PMA_HOST: 10.0.3.3
- PMA_PORT: 33060
- PMA_USER: root
- PMA_PASSWORD: root

However, when loading phpMyAdmin, there are errors:

```
Cannot connect: invalid settings.
 mysqli::real_connect(): Premature end of data (mysqlnd_wireprotocol.c:387)
 mysqli::real_connect(): GREET packet 4 bytes shorter than expected
 mysqli::real_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=30
 mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Unknown error while trying to connect via tcp://10.0.3.3:33060
 phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.
```

Comment: Is mysql configured to accept remote connections?

Comment: I can't see a setting or [env variable](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) where that is set, @Shadow

Comment: You need to configure mysql, not the docker instance. See using custom mysql configuration file on the link you provided in your comment.

Comment: MySQL container is by default ready to remote connection, I guess issue is that default port is `3306` but you have `33060`, so it's not even starting a connection as you have that in the message `the server rejected the connection`. It's rejected as it's not listening on that port

Comment: Beaut, thanks @zori, changing to port `3306` worked beautifully. Add an answer if you like.

Comment: No, when the server rejects the connection it means IT IS listening on that port, otherwise it would give a "Connection refused"

Answer (score 0):

Issue is that default MySQL port is `3306` but you are connecting to `33060`, that is the port that should be used in phpMyAdmin for the connection

Additional note looking at https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql, there is no information about default port for MySQL, so we can get it for for example Google `What is default port for MySQL server`, also we can go to the specific image tag on Docker Hub [mysql:latest](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/mysql/latest/images/sha256-6d5a11994be8ca5e4cfaf4d370219f6eb6ef8fb41d57f9ed1568a93ffd5471ef?context=explore) and look for command `EXPOSE`, in this case we will get `EXPOSE map[3306/tcp:{} 33060/tcp:{}]`.

Additional thing to mention here is port `33060`, if we go deeper we will get it's [Port X Portocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63556825/what-is-the-port-33060-for-mysql-server-ports-in-addition-to-the-port-3306) and it's not what phpMyAdmin expects (this is what I learned form this)

Comment: The OP stated in the question that phpmyadmin is configured to connext to 33060 port.

Comment: And this is the issue it should be `PMA_PORT: 3306`, doc says `PMA_PORT - define port of the MySQL server`, I also a little be rephrased my answer, also his comment in the question says it fixed for him